# if/else statement not calling a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, if-statement, modal-dialog

I am going insane here. I have searched and searched and tried a number of different ways, i'm not getting any errors, but I cant get the if/else statement to call the function it is supposed to be calling. the function itself works fine if called otherwise, just not inside the if statement, what is going on??

oops, ok I deleted the "var" in the second part, but its still behaving a bit weird -- what I want it to do, is when the confirm delete button is pushed, to delete the item and close the modal. what its doing instead, is closing the modal, i have to click delete a second time, and then it deletes the item, and the modal quickly pops up the closes itself.

edit: I changed my code to remove event listeners and use onclick in html instead to see if that was the issue, but its not. im still having the same problem.

```
var clickedCancel = false;
var clickedDelete = false;
//buttons false by defaul
//if cancel button is clicked, set clickedcancel to true.

//if confirm delete button is clicked, set clicked delete to true
function cancelDeletion(){
  clickedCancel = true;
}

function confirmDeletion(){
  clickedDelete = true;
}

function deleteMovie(x){
  //open modal
$('#modalContainerDelete').modal('toggle');


  if (clickedDelete == true){
    movies.splice(x,1);
  addMovieToTable();

  $('#modalContainerDelete').modal('hide');
} else if (clickedCancel == true) {

  $('#modalContainerDelete').modal('hide');
}

};
```

The biggest issue is, my assignment is I need a delete button that removes a specific item from an array, but I have to code the delete button into a row, and delete the same row the delete button is on, and that part is coded this way:

```
function addMovieToTable(){
table.innerHTML = "";
for (i=0;i<movies.length;i++){

var row = table.insertRow(0);
var cellTitle = row.insertCell(0);
var cellDirector = row.insertCell(1);
var cellDelete = row.insertCell(2);
cellTitle.innerHTML= movies[i].title;
cellDirector.innerHTML= movies[i].director;
var deleteStuff = "<button onclick='deleteMovie(" + i + ")'>Delete</button>";
cellDelete.innerHTML = deleteStuff;
}

}
```

the part with the inner html, and the i variable, is what I am trying to code around, I am supposed to make it so before deleting anything, a modal pops up, but this is the main reason im having issues is im trying to code around that without ruining the set up.

Comment: Remove `var` inside `click` handler, Just use `clickedDelete = true;`

Comment: remove `var` inside click handler. you are initializing again and again

Comment: omg hahaha thank you, wow I feel dumb >.>

Comment: ok now, instead of running the code immedietly, its making me click the delete button a second time before it deletes what I want?

Comment: What I want it to do, is when confirm delete is pressed, it deletes what I want, and closes the modal. what it is now doing, is when confirm delete is pressed, it closes the modal, and if i click delete a second time, it deletes it without the modal popping open.

Comment: actually the modal does pop open for a second after the second push but quickly disappears on its own

Comment: You need to set `clickedDelete = false` in the `deleteMovie` function

Comment: where exactly? in the else statement? or ?

Comment: or do you mean after the code is executed?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
var clickedCancel = false;
var clickedDelete = false;
//buttons false by defaul
//if cancel button is clicked, set clickedcancel to true.
var cancelDeletion = document.getElementById("cancelDeletion");
cancelDeletion.addEventListener("click", function () {
    clickedCancel = true;
});
//if confirm delete button is clicked, set clicked delete to true
var confirmDeletion = document.getElementById("deleteConfirm");
confirmDeletion.addEventListener("click", function () {
    clickedDelete = true;
});

function deleteMovie(x) {
    //open modal
    $('#modalContainerDelete').modal('toggle');
    if (clickedDelete == true) {
        movies.splice(x, 1);
        addMovieToTable();
        $('#modalContainerDelete').modal('hide');
    } else if (clickedCancel == true) {
        $('#modalContainerDelete').modal('hide');
    }
};
```

......

Answer (score 0):

you declare clickedCancel clickedDelete twice 
remove the second var and it will work fine.
Also :
its better if you stop the event listener when you done with it and fire it just when you need it to avoid multiple calls

Edit :

Remember if user click cancel button and then try to click delete button it will do nothing because eventlistener still remember the old option ( which is cancel ) thats why you have to find a way to turn that listener off and on to avoid multiple calls. thats why when you try to delete after pressing cancel it didn't work for you  ...

this is an example :

```
    function delete_comment(element, event){
        event.preventDefault();
        // get the post id
        var post_id    = $(element).parents("div.IdHolderDiv").attr("id");
        // get comment id
        var comment_id = $(element).parents('div.singleCommentBox').find('div.CommentdialogboxUnderPOST').attr('id');
    // here is the confirmation button (where user press cancel or delete)
        var confirmBox  = "<div id='confirm_delete_comment' class='w3-modal'>";
            confirmBox += "<div class='alert warning' >";
            confirmBox += "<center><br><br>";
            confirmBox += "<p>Are you sure you want to delete this Comment!</p>";
            confirmBox += "<button class='w3-btn w3-ripple w3-red' > Delete</button>";
            confirmBox += "<button class='w3-btn w3-ripple w3-yellow' > Cancel</button>";
            confirmBox += "<br><br></center></div></div>";
// append the confirmation box to your Dom in an empty div
        $('#confirm_delete').append(confirmBox);
        // make that div visable
        // confirmation message.
        $('#confirm_delete_comment').css('display', 'block');

        // wait user confirmation.
// and here you fire the event listener
        $("#confirm_delete_comment").on("click", "button", function(event){
            event.preventDefault(); 
            var confirm = $(this).text().trim();
// check if user says cancel or delete and then you can turn the listener off
            if( confirm == "Delete" ){
                $.post('public/ajax/delete_comment.php', {post_id:post_id, comment_id:comment_id}, function(data){
                    $.post('public/ajax/comment_get.php', {post_id:post_id}, function(data){
                        // change the counter (comment number at the id of that specific post for full modle and index page)
                        $('#post_'+post_id+'_comments').text(data); 
                        if(indexPage.length){
                            $('#showPostFullScreen #post_'+post_id+'_comments').text(data); 
                        }else if(profilePage.length){
                            $('#showPostFullScreenProfile #post_'+post_id+'_comments').text(data); 
                        }
                        // reload comments.
                        if( $('#modal_post').css('display') == 'none' ){
                            load_comments(post_id); 
                        }else if( $('#modal_post').css('display') == 'block' ){
                            load_commentsFull(post_id);

                        }

                    });
                    // get the notifications
                    load_notifications();
                });
                // remove listner. for older than 1.7 $('#infoarea_display_editon button').unbind('click');
                $('#confirm_delete_comment').off('click button');
                $('#confirm_delete').empty();
            }else if( confirm == "Cancel" ){
                $('#confirm_delete_comment').off('click button');
                $('#confirm_delete').empty();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: how would I stop the event listener when im done with it?

Comment: depends on your code .. for ex : if user click the delete button then inside function deleteMovie(x){ at the end of this function you write this ( $('#cancelDeletion').off('click'); ) this will turn off the listener.

Comment: and remember if user click cancel button and then try to click delete button it will do nothing because eventlistener still remember the old option ( which is cancel ) thats why you have to find a way to turn that listener off and on to avoid multiple calls

Comment: where would I put that exactly? in the if/else statement or after?

Comment: also, would it make a difference if i used something in jquery instead of the eventlistener?

Comment: is the confirm button exist in your Dom or you append it using jquery ? if its in the Dom then can't turn it off otherwise users can't delete or cancel any more .... if the confirmation button appended to your code using jquery then you can do that ..... ( i will put an example on the answer above to make this comment clear )

Comment: the confirm deletion and cancel deletion buttons are in the dom

Comment: is there a way to do an onclick like you would do in html <button onclick=""> in jquery ?

Comment: since they are in the dom then you can't turn the listener off otherwise the users can delete or cancel anymore !! it should keep listening.

Comment: oh boy. so i would need to delete those from the html and then code them with jquery?

Comment: best way to do this is by appending your confirmation button once the user click on delete then you display msg (ex: are you sure ? delete cancel ) if he choose cancel then you turn off the listener and if user try to delete again then you can append the confirmation msg again and fire the listener

Comment: Yup thats much better and cleaner ... unless you have a way to turn that listener off and on without preventing users from multiple cancel or multiple deletion ... look closer to your code and then decide if there is a way or not .... ( and don't worry i been in your situation with somthing similar couple  months ago.. thats why i know what the problem is ..good luck

Comment: ok so i tried something different i removed the event listeners and did onclicks in the html code but im having the same issue anyways so those werent the problem

Comment: the problem now is : you can't keep waiting inside the function until onclick comes back to you with user response ! and you need to make them in tow different functions ... if your situation in this code allow this kind of scenario then go ahead

Comment: oh man. ok hahah >.> so here is my biggest issue is I am trying to work around another piece of code which is throwing this all off. the actual delete button in question is something that has to be inserted into the html in order to delete the row its on, but the assignment is that when the delete button is pushed, a modal has to pop up, before it deletes, but in order for it to delete the right row, it has to call a function with a specific variable and i dont know how to fix this without messing that part up.. i'll put that above one sec